# Filestream only reading the first 4 characters of the file

Tags: c#, file, io

Hey there! I'm trying to read a 150mb file with a file stream but every time I do it all I get is: `|zl` instead of the whole stream. Note that it has some special characters in it.

Does anybody know what the problem could be? here is my code:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    extract = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
}
```

Edit:
I tried to read all text but it still returned the same four characters. It works fine on any other file except for these few. When I use read all lines it only gets the first line.

Comment: Are you sure that the file is a text file? If `File.ReadAllText` only returns four characters, then it's a good bet that the rest of the file isn't text. Or I guess it could be that `path` isn't pointing to the file you think it's pointing to. Check the return value of `fs.Read` to make sure you're actually reading as much data as you think you are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`fs.Read()` does not read the whole smash of bytes all at once, it reads some number of bytes and returns the number of bytes read. MSDN has an excellent example of how to use it to get the whole file:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx

For what it's worth, reading the entire 150MB of data into memory is really going to put a drain on your client's system -- the preferred option would be to optimize it so that you don't need the whole file all at once.

Comment: This is why memory mapped files are a better solution for this.

Comment: Thanks, i was unaware of this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read text this way File.ReadAllLine (or ReadAllText) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx is better option.

My guess the file is not text file to start with and the way you display resulting string does stop at 0 characters.

As debracey pointed out Read returns number of bytes read - check that out. Also for file operations it is unlikely to stop at 4 characters...

Comment: I did this but it returned the same string. I also just tested the above and i still only got the first four. When I use read all lines it only gets the first line.