# How can I process the response stream from a webpage that displays a video?

Tags: vb.net, video, stream, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

```
<html>
    <body style="background-color: rgb(38,38,38);">
        <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media"
            style="margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;"
            src="http://av.vimeo.com/32372/157/24910156.mp4?token=1322514534_58acf41d56103820e9fe93763c73fadd">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

Above is the response of the page I am trying to get if I enter [the URL](http://av.vimeo.com/32372/157/24910156.mp4?token=1322514534_58acf41d56103820e9fe93763c73fadd):

However, the program just crashes with the following code (i.e. never even displays final - meaning stream is still going on)

I think that it is streaming the video, in addition to the source- which I do not want to happen

How can I retrieve this source?

```
Dim final As String = ""
Dim request1 As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(urlvimeohd), HttpWebRequest)

request1.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1"
Dim response1 As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request1.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

final = New StreamReader(response1.GetResponseStream).ReadToEnd
MessageBox.Show(final)
```

I just want the source of the webpage. When I try `webbrowser1.navigate`, the source just says "technical difficulties". How  can I proceed?

Comment: Are you want to get the sourcecode of the page in response stream?

Comment: @m.qayyum Exactly: without downloading the video!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HttpWebRequest request = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(Url), HttpWebRequest)HttpWebResponse resp = DirectCast(request.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
string sourcecode = New StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream,System.Text.Encoding.Default).ReadToEnd
```

replace Url with your link

Comment: http://av.vimeo.com/32372/157/24910156.mp4?token=1322514534_58acf41d56103820e9fe93763c73fadd this link is not availale, so you are requesting a url that is not existing and giving you error....i think you want to get information of .mp4 file which is on that site....

Comment: don't worry the link works (my program generates a new one each time)!

Comment: usually .mp4 files does not contain html source code...try to read first few bytes of the file and then check that file...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863786/filestream-only-reading-the-first-4-characters-of-the-file