# how to retrieve post httpresponse data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, post, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have a part of code that sends a post httprequest to weburl and then the response is again in post method , how can I get the posted data from httpresponse :

```
Dim request1 As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("some url here"     & str)
    request1.Method = "POST"
    request1.CookieContainer = cookie
    enc = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
    postdatabytes = enc.GetBytes(postdt)

    request1.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ' request1.ContentType = "application/json"
    request1.ContentLength = postdatabytes.Length
    'Dim strn As New StreamWriter(request1.GetRequestStream())
    'strn.Write(postdt)
    'strn.Close()

    Using stream = request1.GetRequestStream()
        stream.Write(postdatabytes, 0, postdatabytes.Length)


    End Using

    Dim r As String


    Dim response1 As HttpWebResponse = request1.GetResponse()
    If response1.Method = "POST" Then
        '' here I want to get response data
    End If
```

After a long searching I didnt find any answer ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8302655/1070452 might help  or this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse(v=vs.110).aspx  or this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6554/How-to-use-HttpWebRequest-and-HttpWebResponse-in-N

Comment: first thanks for fast reply ,but the provided links are describing to get response data from body of httpwebresponse , but in my case the request has a response with method "POST" ,I mean the body of response is empty but it contains data in InputStream of response and I cant find way to retrieve data from inputstream of httpwebresponse ...