# Read n first Characters of a big Text File - C#

Tags: c#

I have a very big text file, for example about 1 GB. I need to just read 100 first characters and nothing more.

I searched StackOverflow and other forums but all of them have some solutions which first read the whole file and then will return some n characters of the file.

I do not want to read and load the whole file into memory etc. just need the first characters.

Comment: Read each bytes and convert it as a charactor

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863786/filestream-only-reading-the-first-4-characters-of-the-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filestream only reading the first 4 characters of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863786/filestream-only-reading-the-first-4-characters-of-the-file)

Comment: It depends on your encoding. You would need to read `Encoding.GetMaxByteCount(n)` bytes, let the encoder encode the bytes to characters and select the first n.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`StreamReader.ReadBlock()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readblock?view=netframework-4.7.2) to read a specified number of characters from a file:

```
public static char[] ReadChars(string filename, int count)
{
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        char[] buffer = new char[count];
        int n = reader.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, count);

        char[] result = new char[n];

        Array.Copy(buffer, result, n);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Note that this assumes that your file has UTF8 encoding. If it doesn't, you'll need to specify the correct encoding (in which case you could add an encoding parameter to `ReadChars()` rather than hard-coding it).

The advantage of using `ReadBlock()` rather than `Read()` is that it blocks until either all the characters have been read, or the end of the file has been reached. However, for a `FileStream` this is of no consequence; just be aware that `Read()` can return less bytes than asked for in the general case, even if the end of the stream has not been reached.

If you want an `async` version you can just call `ReadBlockAsync()` like so:

```
public static async Task<char[]> ReadCharsAsync(string filename, int count)
{
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        char[] buffer = new char[count];
        int n = await reader.ReadBlockAsync(buffer, 0, count);

        char[] result = new char[n];

        Array.Copy(buffer, result, n);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Which you might call like so:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            string filename = "Your filename here";
            Console.WriteLine(await ReadCharsAsync(filename, 100));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't work as OP wants to read n characters, not n bytes and one characters can be up to 6 bytes in UTF8. As mentioned in my comment you need to call GetMaxByteCount for your encoding.

Comment: I see now, my bad.

Answer (score 4):

Let's read with `StreamReader`:

```
  char[] buffer = new char[100];

  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\MyFile.txt")) {
    // Technically, StreamReader can read less than buffer.Length characters
    // if the file is too short; 
    // in this case reader.Read returns the number of actually read chars
    reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  }
```

Comment: you probably mean `StreamReader`; `StringReader` literally reads from a `string`, no?

Comment: @Marc Gravell: You quite right; I'm sorry for the typo

Comment: Watch out for `Read()` - it can return less characters than asked for in some cases, even if there are more available, because it doesn't block. In the case of a file, however, this should be fine. (This is why Microsoft added the `ReadBlock()` method.)

Comment: Also watch out for files less than 100 characters long - this method will leave one or more `0` chars at the end of the array in that scenario, which may or may not be OK.

Answer (score 2):

`fs.Read();` does not read the whole bytes all at once, it reads some number of bytes and returns the number of bytes read. MSDN has a good example of how to use it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx

Reading the entire 1 GB of data into memory is really going to put a drain on your client's system -- the preferred option would be to optimize it so that you don't need the whole file all at once.